# Change body's background color every time div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

When the button div is clicked I would like to change the body to a random color in the "colors" array. This code works, but it only works the first time I click. What can I change for the body to change color EVERY time the div is clicked?

```
var colors = ["#3b609b", "#9b3b3b", "#3b9b81", "#7da5a4"];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

$(".button").click(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", colors[rand]);
})
```

Comment: put this line `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);`  in your click function ;)

Comment: you set `rand`  only once, but you want to set it every time a `div` is clicked

Comment: @d3vi4nt Wow, can't believe I missed that thanks it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In your code, the value of `rand` variable remains same for every click.

You will need to update this value in each click so put this line of code `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)` in click handler.

```js
var colors = ["#3b609b", "#9b3b3b", "#3b9b81", "#7da5a4"];


$(".button").click(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  $("body").css("background-color", colors[rand]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Gaurav</h1>
<button class="button"> Change Color</button>
```

Comment: @Zach happy coding